# Difference between "%" macros and "$" macros in MSVS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I'm new to MSVS2010. I'm porting a solution from MSVS2005 to MSVS2010. We used Intel Compiler 9.1 and now Intel Compiler 12.1. So the projects were previously splited in two files: *.vcproj and *.icproj. Now they are saved only in one file: *.vcxproj.

Well. I see some place where %(MACRONAME) macros are used. I knew $(MACRONAME) like $(OutDir) but **what does %(...) mean?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

%(*ItemMetadataName*) is [MSBuild batching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171473.aspx) syntax. There is Target batching an Task batching, both are used to iterate through targets or tasks based on item's metadata.